# Something wrong with my Pivot function but I literally don't know why

Tags: sql-server

I have  table that has Order_Day,Product_ID, Quantity and Price columns:

```
create table dbo.AmazonTestTable
(order_day date,
order_id  int,
product_id char(2),
quantity int,
price int)
go

insert into dbo.AmazonTestTable values
('01-JUL-11',1,'p1',5,5),
('01-JUL-11',2,'p2',2,10),
('01-JUL-11',3,'p3',10,25),
('01-JUL-11',4,'p1',20,5),
('02-JUL-11',5,'p3',5,25),
('02-JUL-11',6,'p4',6,20),
('02-JUL-11',7,'p1',2,5),
('02-JUL-11',8,'p5',1,50),
('02-JUL-11',9,'p6',2,50),
('02-JUL-11',10,'p2',4,10)
go
```

The problem is that I want to select order_day, product_id, and TotalSales(this can be calculated by using quantity multiple by price) and then pivot it. So the pivoted table should have three columns: product_id, '01-JUL-11','02-JUL-11'. So I use the codes below:

```
select product_id,'2011-07-01' as TotalSalesOnDay1,'2011-07-02' as 
TotalSalesOnDay2
from (select product_id,order_day,(quantity*price) as TotalSales
      from dbo.AmazonTestTable) as TotalSalesPerDay
pivot
(sum(TotalSales) for [order_day] in ([2011-07-01] ,[2011-07-02] )) as 
PivotDataSet;
go
```

but it returns the result as below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`'2011-07-01'` is a constant string.  The escape method in SQL Server uses square braces:

```
select product_id, [2011-07-01] as TotalSalesOnDay1, [2011-07-02] as TotalSalesOnDay2
. . .
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will do the trick -

```
;With PivotData
As
(
    Select 
        product_id, -- grouping element
        order_day, -- spreading element
        (quantity * price) As TotalSales -- aggregating element
    From AmazonTestTable
)
Select
    product_id, [2011-07-01] As TotalSalesDay1, [2011-07-02] As TotalSalesDay2
From PivotData
Pivot (Sum(TotalSales) For order_day In ([2011-07-01], [2011-07-02])) As P
```

It will give you the following output -

```
product_id  TotalSalesDay1  TotalSalesDay2
p1          125             10
p2          20              40
p4          NULL            120
p3          250             125
p5          NULL            50
p6          NULL            100
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this

```
    SELECT product_id, order_day, SUM(TotalSales) AS TotalSales FROM 
       (SELECT product_id,order_day,(quantity*price) as TotalSales
       FROM AmazonTestTable) AS TotalSalesPerDay
    GROUP BY TotalSalesPerDay.order_day;
```

The output will be:

```
product_id| order_day | TotalSales
p1        | 01-JUL-11 |395
p2        | 02-JUL-11 |445
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen hundreds of pivot questions here in the past few months.  Let me post some sample solutions, and maybe help others to learn the basics, so we don't keep seeing the same thing over and over and over.

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
 product VARCHAR(30),
 market_year INT,
 value INT,
 quantity INT,
 CONSTRAINT pk_products
 PRIMARY KEY (product, market_year));

INSERT INTO Products VALUES('Corn', 2003, 100, 20);
INSERT INTO Products VALUES('Corn', 2004, 200, 25);
INSERT INTO Products VALUES('Corn', 2005, 150, 30);
INSERT INTO Products VALUES('Corn', 2006, 150, 10);

SELECT product,
       SUM(CASE WHEN market_year = 2003 THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS v2003,
       SUM(CASE WHEN market_year = 2003 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS q2003,
       SUM(CASE WHEN market_year = 2004 THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS v2004,
       SUM(CASE WHEN market_year = 2004 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS q2004,
       SUM(CASE WHEN market_year = 2005 THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS v2005,
       SUM(CASE WHEN market_year = 2005 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS q2005,
       SUM(CASE WHEN market_year = 2006 THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS v2006,
       SUM(CASE WHEN market_year = 2006 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS q2006
FROM Products
GROUP BY product;
```

Result:

```
product v2003   q2003   v2004   q2004   v2005   q2005   v2006   q2006
Corn    100 20  200 25  150 30  150 10
```

Also . . .

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO
-- Creating Test Table
CREATE TABLE Product(Cust VARCHAR(25), Product VARCHAR(20), QTY INT)
GO
-- Inserting Data into Table
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('KATE','VEG',2)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('KATE','SODA',6)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('KATE','MILK',1)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('KATE','BEER',12)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('FRED','MILK',3)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('FRED','BEER',24)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('KATE','VEG',3)
GO
-- Selecting and checking entires in table
SELECT *
FROM Product
GO
-- Pivot Table ordered by PRODUCT
SELECT PRODUCT, FRED, KATE
FROM (
SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
FROM Product) up
PIVOT (SUM(QTY) FOR CUST IN (FRED, KATE)) AS pvt
ORDER BY PRODUCT
GO
-- Pivot Table ordered by CUST
SELECT CUST, VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS
FROM (
SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
FROM Product) up
PIVOT (SUM(QTY) FOR PRODUCT IN (VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS)) AS pvt
ORDER BY CUST
GO
-- Unpivot Table ordered by CUST
SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
FROM
(
SELECT CUST, VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS
FROM (
SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
FROM Product) up
PIVOT
( SUM(QTY) FOR PRODUCT IN (VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS)) AS pvt) p
UNPIVOT
(QTY FOR PRODUCT IN (VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS)
) AS Unpvt
GO
-- Clean up database
DROP TABLE Product
GO

ResultSet:
-- Selecting and checking entires in table
Cust Product QTY
------------------------- -------------------- -----------
KATE VEG 2
KATE SODA 6
KATE MILK 1
KATE BEER 12
FRED MILK 3
FRED BEER 24
KATE VEG 3

-- Pivot Table ordered by PRODUCT
PRODUCT FRED KATE
-------------------- ----------- -----------
BEER 24 12
MILK 3 1
SODA NULL 6
VEG NULL 5

-- Pivot Table ordered by CUST
CUST VEG SODA MILK BEER CHIPS
------------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
FRED NULL NULL 3 24 NULL
KATE 5 6 1 12 NULL

-- Unpivot Table ordered by CUST
CUST PRODUCT QTY
------------------------- -------- -----------
FRED MILK 3
FRED BEER 24
KATE VEG 5
KATE SODA 6
KATE MILK 1
KATE BEER 12 12
```

You can even do a dynamic pivot, when you don't know, ahead of time, all the fields that you will be dealing with.  Let SQL Server do the work for you!!

```
--Create Temporary Table #CourseSales
CREATE TABLE #CourseSales
(Course VARCHAR(50),Year INT,Earning MONEY)
GO
--Populate Sample records
INSERT INTO #CourseSales VALUES('.NET',2012,10000)
INSERT INTO #CourseSales VALUES('Java',2012,20000)
INSERT INTO #CourseSales VALUES('.NET',2012,5000)
INSERT INTO #CourseSales VALUES('.NET',2013,48000)
INSERT INTO #CourseSales VALUES('Java',2013,30000)
GO

SELECT *
FROM #CourseSales
PIVOT(SUM(Earning) 
      FOR Course IN ([.NET], Java)) AS PVTTable
```

You will find some great resources here!

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/understanding-sql-server-2000-pivot/

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/dynamic-pivot-on-multiple-columns/